# gzipstream truncating my xml

Tags: xml, powershell, stream, gzip

I am attempting to serialize my powershell objects and send them over a tcp connection. As such I can't read or write my XML to a file, as that would be a waste of time for something that should be able to happen in memory only. i have a wonderful convertfrom-xml script obtained from here that seems to work: http://poshcode.org/2294

In order to keept he size of my packets down, and perhaps provide just a teensy bit of security by obscurity, I am attempting to compress the objects while they travel, using gzipstream. i've also tried deflatestream. neither of them seem to be working for me.

```
$o = ""|select x,y,z,a
$o.x = 3
$o.y = "hello"
$o.z = [datetime]::now
$o.a = 1..9
$xml = $o | convertto-xml
$mem = new-object system.io.memorystream
$gz = new-object system.io.compression.gzipstream($mem, [system.io.compression.compressionmode]::compress)
$xml.save($gz)
$bytes = $mem.toarray()
$gz.close()
$mem.close()
```

This part successfully gives me an array of bytes that seem compressed.

```
$mem = new-object system.io.memorystream(,$bytes)
$gz = new-object system.io.compression.gzipstream($mem, [system.io.compression.compressionmode]::decompress)
$gz.flush()
$xml = new-object xml
$xml.load($gz)
$o = $xml | convertfrom-xml
$gz.close()
$mem.close()
```

this part fails on the line `$xml.load($gz)`, saying the Root element is missing. I thus try and read from $gz directly, and get a -1 to begin with (which i thought meant the end of the stream?), and then immediately after the first -1, i get the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
    <Property Name="x" Type="System.Int32">3</Property>
    <Property Name="y" Type="System.String">hello</Property>
    <Property Name="z" Type="System.DateTime">16/08/2014 11:43:48 PM</Property>
    <Property Name="a" Type="System.Object[]">
      <Property Type="System.Int32">1</Property>
      <Property Type="System.Int32">2</Property>
      <Property Type="System.Int32">3</Property>
      <Property Type="System.Int32">4</Property>
      <Property Type="System.Int32">5</Property>
      <Property Type="System.Int32">6</Property>
      <Property Type="System.Int32">7</Property>
      <Property Type="System.Int32">8</Property>
      <Property Type="System.Int32">9</Property>
    </Property>
  </Object>
```

i then tried a few other things to get it to work, including replacing gzipstream with deflatestream, flushing $gz, and reading from $gz to a third stream. None of them have helped with either the initial -1 or the truncating of my xml. what is causing these two issues?

I suspect my main problem is my only rudimentary familiarity with streams.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this for you, didn't truncate enclosed file

http://wannemacher.us/?p=225

My original file was 39689 bytes, this made it 475 (I just copied that object block over and over and closed the objects tag).

Here's that example adapted using a memorystream -

```
$inFile = "C:\Users\andy\Desktop\compressit.txt"

$input = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $inFile, ([IO.FileMode]::Open), ([IO.FileAccess]::Read), ([IO.FileShare]::Read)
$buffer = New-Object byte[]($input.Length)
$byteCount = $input.Read($buffer, 0, $input.Length)
$input.Close()

$output = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream

$gzipStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GzipStream $output, ([IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Compress)
$gzipStream.Write($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
$gzipStream.Close()

# Show the results
$output.ToArray() | Set-Content -Path ($inFile + '.gz') -Encoding Byte

$output.Close()
```

Comment: yes but i can't use a file, it has to all be in memory.

Comment: @nacht just the output from a file stream to a memorystream.

Comment: @Nacht I added an example using memorystream for you

Comment: ... Please note my edit. i need to do this _without reading/writing to disk_.